# Avoiding alliteration in 'respective perspectives' - how?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I've got a sentence here I cant get working:

> Direct and in-depth discussion with the providers followed, this was
>   done concurrently with X with Y providing a parallel analysis,
>   inspired by our ***respective perspectives***.

'respective perspectives' sounds silly, but it is about as factually correct I can get.

Using synonyms for each and working through the combinations yields either worse results or something that sounds ok to read, but isn't as accurate in terms of the intended meaning.

Example synonyms:

**Respective**:

- particular
- individual
- own

**Perspective**:

- outlook
- point of view
- position
- approach

etc.

Anyone got a way to make this work?

Comment: Individual approach is just fine

Comment: @vickyace That is an example of "something that sounds ok to read, but isn't as accurate in terms of the intended meaning". Unfortunately 'we' are two groups of individuals - a group of groups. By using 'individual perspectives' it may lead someone to ask '*which* individuals?'. 'Respective' is more ambiguous, which is helpful in this regard.

Comment: 'individual' certainly stuck around for a while, but I've opted for 'own perspectives' in the meantime, mostly because of the fact I cant state what is wrong with it (it still doesn't sit well though)

Comment: I think "our own perspectives" will also work because you're two distinct groups and I believe each group will have a representative to speak on their behalf.

Comment: Too many Ps: providers providing parallel analysis inspired by respective perspectives.  Eliminating one of them does not get you out of the woods.

Comment: I'd say "both our perspectives" if you want to say that the perspectives differ. I must agree there are still too many Ps left over though.

Answer (score 1):

"Separate" or "distinct" paired with almost anything in the second list (including "perspectives") might work.